# Button Not Appearing from Loop

Tags: java, loops, applet

I am having a problem making a Java Applet, I am trying to get **3 separate** buttons to appear on the screen then preform an action when clicked. I have created a for loop, and have the addition of the buttons inside, yet when I run the program, no buttons appear. Any suggestions?

```
public class CPT extends Applet
{
    Button Holland, Cuba, Russia, USACal, Austria, Colombia, China, SouthKor, Bangladesh, DomRep;
    int ranDeal;
    Label title;
    Font f;
    Image globe, signs, plane;

public void init ()
    {
        Button Holland = new Button ("Holland");
        Button Cuba = new Button ("Cuba");
        Button Russia = new Button ("Russia");
        Button USACal = new Button ("USA - Cali.");
        Button Austria = new Button ("Austria");
        Button Colombia = new Button ("Colombia");
        Button China = new Button ("China");
        Button SouthKor = new Button ("South Korea");
        Button Bangladesh = new Button ("Bangladesh");
        Button DomRep = new Button ("Dom. Rep.");

    for (int j = 0 ; j >= 4 ; j++)
    {

        ranDeal = (int) (Math.random () * 10);

        if (ranDeal == 1)
        {

            add (Holland);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 2)
        {

            add (Cuba);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 3)
        {

            add (Russia);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 4)
        {

            add (USACal);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 5)
        {

            add (Austria);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 6)
        {

            add (Colombia);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 7)
        {

            add (China);
        }

        else if (ranDeal == 8)
        {

            add (SouthKor);
        }
        else if (ranDeal == 9)
        {

            add (Bangladesh);
        }
        else
        {

            add (DomRep);



        }

    }
```

Comment: 1) Change the applet's layout manager from BorderLayout to something else, perhaps FlowLayout. 2) You're not accounting for if the random variable is 0. 3) You should use the Swing GUI library, not the AWT one. **Edit**: and what Peter just posted! 1+ to him for catching that.

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.  E.G. `Button Holland` should be `Button holland`..

Comment: The entire `if .. else' structure would be better handled as either a `Button[]` array or `switch` statement.  You should have covered both these 'Programming 101' concepts before approaching GUI development, let alone applets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never enter this loop.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j >= 4 ; j++)
```

I guess you meant.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)
```

Also, the logic in your `for` loop has this issue that it can select the same button more than once and respectively try to add it more than once.

Comment: @Andrew It happens to everyone :) Good luck.

Comment: @Andrew: if you don't feel like an idiot every now and then when programming, you're doing something wrong. Good catch peter.petrov!